# Vaadin Flow: Remove PollListener

Tags: vaadin, polling, vaadin-flow

Is there a possibility to remove a `PollListener` in Vaadin 14?

```
UI.getCurrent().addPollListener(pollEvent -> { refresh(); }
```

I need to start refreshing, but if the Route or UI is changed, the refreshing has to stop.

Is there a "Vaadin possibility" for that, or do I have to build something on my own?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in the [docs](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.6.1/com/vaadin/flow/component/UI.html#setPollInterval-int-), in order to disable polling, one should call

```
UI.getCurrent().setPollInterval(-1);
```

In order to ensure that this is called upon navigating away from the view, you can make this call from within a [BeforeLeaveObserver](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/routing/tutorial-routing-lifecycle/#beforeleaveevent). Here is an example:

```
public class Foo extends Div
        implements BeforeLeaveObserver {
    @Override
    public void beforeLeave(BeforeLeaveEvent event) {
        UI.getCurrent().setPollInterval(-1);
    }

}
```

If you want to remove a single poll listener while keeping polling enabled, you can store a reference to the `Registration` object returned by the `addPollListener()` method and then call the `remove` method from the `Registration`.

Comment: Worth noting that the `addPollListener` returns a `Registration`, and you can call `Registration#remove` to remove it. This is useful if you ever want to remove a listener without disabling the polling.